# Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made

Tags: table-of-contents, latexmk

when I compile my .tex file, the following message appears:

Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.

A .toc has been created. But sometimes the error message says that none was created.

Here is my minimal example

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{obsblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.42,0.7}
\definecolor{obsyellow}{rgb}{1,0.79,0.165}
\definecolor{obsdarkblue}{rgb}{0.09,0.286,0.580}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{enhanced,
before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm,
colback=obsyellow!30,colframe=obsdarkblue,boxrule=0.8mm,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
boxed title style={frame code={
\path[fill=tcbcolback!30!black]
([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
\path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black,right color=tcbcolback!60!black,
middle color=tcbcolback!80!black]
([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
[rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
-- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
[sharp corners]-- cycle;
},interior engine=empty,
},
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={#2},#1}



\begin{document}
        \section[Homework Collection]{Homework Collection}
        \subsection[Electricity theory]{Electricity theory}
        \begin{mybox}[colbacktitle=obsblue]{Electricity theory}
            description
        \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

On another PC with identical MikTex installation the .tex file is compiled without problems.

What could be the reasons for this error message.

Here is the complete output:

```
Win CP console initial and current in/out Win: (850, 65001), (1252, 1252)
Coding system for system and terminal: 'CP1252'
---
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Mar. 2022. Version 4.77, version: 4.77.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
  //fileserver/users/Username/Desktop/Minimalexample/Minimalexample.tex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
  pdflatex
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  --max-print-line=10000 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "//fileserver/users/Username/Desktop/Minimalexample/Minimalexample.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.8.28) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(//fileserver/users/Username/Desktop/Minimalexample/Minimalexample.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-30> (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/exam\exam.cls
Document Class: exam 2021/02/26 Version 2.7 by Philip Hirschhorn
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size12.clo))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex-dev/graphics\mathcolor.ltx)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/varwidth\varwidth.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/colortbl\colortbl.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\array.sty)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcolorbox.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\verbatim.sty) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/environ\environ.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/trimspaces\trimspaces.sty)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbraster.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbraster.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbskins.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskins.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbbreakable.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/oberdiek\pdfcol.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbhooks.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbhooks.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbtheorems.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbtheorems.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbfitting.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbfitting.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcblistingsutf8.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingsutf8.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcblistings.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistings.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/listings\listings.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/listings\lstmisc.sty) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/listings\listings.cfg)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcblistingscore.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbprocessing.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbprocessing.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty)))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/listingsutf8\listingsutf8.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/stringenc\stringenc.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty)))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbexternal.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbexternal.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbmagazine.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbmagazine.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbvignette.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbvignette.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryfadings.code.tex))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbposter.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbposter.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def) (Minimalexample.aux) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty) [1{C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
This exam contains 0 questions with 0 parts, 0 subparts, and 0 subsubparts.
This exam has a total of 0 points.
This exam has a total of 0 bonus points.

Class exam Warning: Point totals have changed. Rerun to get point totals right.

(Minimalexample.aux) )<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on Minimalexample.pdf (1 page, 34776 bytes).
SyncTeX written on Minimalexample.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Minimalexample.log.
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.
----------------------
This message may duplicate earlier message.
Latexmk: Failure in processing file '//fileserver/users/Username/Desktop/Minimalexample/Minimalexample':
   *LaTeX didn't generate the expected log file 'Minimalexample.log'
----------------------
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (850,65001)
Latexmk: Getting log file 'Minimalexample.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'Minimalexample.log'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'Minimalexample.pdf'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: gave an error
```

Comment: I see the .tex file is on a server.  So I suspect that there is a problem with how latexmk and Windows treat filenames with a server component, which may need a correction to latexmk.   But to test my suspicion, I need some diagnostic information. I note also that latexmk's output also says that it didn't find the .log file. Do the .fls and .log files actually exist?  If so, in what directory?  What is the name of the working directory?

Comment: the name of the working directory is Minimalexample. Yes the .fls and .log files are indeed present.